# How to combine react-mentions and tinymce-react

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, mention

I'm using in editor TinyMCE with this library [tinymce-react][1] (wrapper of [tinymce][2]) 
and also want to add mention suggestions (@mention). so I used in [react-mentions][3]. 
but I can't success to combine them because react-mention create textarea (MentionsInput) (and this is work fine alone). but I want to use in TinyMCE Editor as a textarea of react-mentions (that he will apply on him).

There is a way to combine them ? or anything else ?

**NOTE:** I know that has a premium plugin(mentions) in TinyMCE but its not a option to purchase him. In addition I must to use in TinyMCE Editor. 
[1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-react): https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-react 
[2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinymce): https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinymce 
[3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mentions): https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mentions